# passing object from c# to c++

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I've been working on a prototype code application that runs in C# and uses classes and functions from older C++ code (in the form of an imported DLL). The code requirement is to pass in a class object to the unmanaged C++ DLL (from C#) and have it be stored/modified for retrieval later by the C# application. Here's the code I have so far...

Simple C++ DLL Class:

```
EXPORT_DLL int init(MyInitParams *initparams);
```

C++ DLL Functions:

```
struct MyInitParams {
public:
    int _np;
    int _nm;
    int type;
    double *CV_Weight;}
```

in c# DLL

```
[DllImport("NEWUSEMPC", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "init")]
    public static extern int init(InitParams parameters);
```

in c# class

```
class InitParams
{
            public int _np;
            public int _nm;
            public int type;
            public double[] CV_Weight;}
```

Comment: You haven't told us what is wrong with your code yet. Please explain what is wrong and what you've done to try to resolve it.

Comment: me data don't correct transport to C++ from c#

Comment: How to ask a good question is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you own the code of the c++ dll it would be a lot more convenient for you to include it in your solution, and create an interop between c# and c++ using managed c++ as a translation layer. Be aware, that the managed c++ layer should only do the translation of data and invoke the native method, and literally nothing else, because managed c++ is designed only as a bridge between the native and managed world.

You can also use mixed debugger to check out what is happening in both managed and unmanaged code in debug to take a look on the variables, so that you can see what's missing.

I personally would discourage the use of platform invoke instead of an interop class, because the latter is a lot cleaner and is easier to maintain later on.